# JFrame.repaint() and JFrame.revalidate() not working

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class TheSize extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    static String inText="";
    JPanel pane=new JPanel();
    JLabel word0=new JLabel("I would like my grid to be 2^",JLabel.RIGHT);
    JLabel word1=new JLabel("*  2^ "+inText,JLabel.RIGHT);
    JButton finish=new JButton("I'm done");
    JTextField size=new JTextField("",3);

    public TheSize(){
        super("size");
        System.out.println("hi");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(550,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout box=new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(box);
        pane.add(word0);
        pane.add(size);
        pane.add(word1);
        pane.add(finish);
        finish.addActionListener(this);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        size. addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                    );
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ignore error
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        inText=size.getText();
        pane.revalidate();
        pane.repaint();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TheSize();
    }


}
```

**a couple of things**

I made sure the KeyListener is working, and it is not working as in no output, it didn't give me any error.

**What should happen:**

It should pop a frame which says I would like my grid to be 2^__(user input Textfield)____* 2^(what is in the textfield). (Button for I'm done).

[image]

however, (what is in the textfield) remains empty after I type something into the text field. I checked whether the program heard my keystrokes using `System.out.println();`, and it is working, so the `revalidate();` and `repaint()` commands must not be(I also tested it out by putting a System.out.println(); in my constructor. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use a KeyListener on a JTextField. Get rid of the KeyListener and the JTextField should likely accept text just fine. Instead, if you want to register user input, use a DocumentListener if you just want the text but won't filter it, or a DocumentFilter if you need to filter the text *before* it is displayed. This sort of question has been asked **many** times on this site.

Also note that your JLabel will never change, even if you do use a DocumentListener since you call `setText(...)` on your word1 JLabel but never re-call this method. Just changing the String that the inText String variable refers to of course will not magically change the JLabel's displayed text.

Note, that I'm not sure what you mean by the `replicate()` command as I've not heard of this method. Do you mean `revalidate()` if so, please clarify.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

// Avoid extending JFrames if at all possible.
// and only extend other components if needed.
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TheSize2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String FORMAT = "*  2^ %s";
   private static final int PREF_W = 550;
   private static final int PREF_H = 100;
   private String inText = "";
   private JLabel word0 = new JLabel("I would like my grid to be 2^", JLabel.RIGHT);
   private JLabel word1 = new JLabel(String.format(FORMAT, inText), JLabel.RIGHT);
   private JButton finish = new JButton("I'm done");
   private JTextField size = new JTextField("", 3);

   public TheSize2() {
      finish.setAction(new FinishAction("I'm Done"));
      size.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new SizeListener());
      add(word0);
      add(size);
      add(word1);
      add(finish);
   }

   @Override // make JPanel bigger
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSz;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
      int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   private class SizeListener implements DocumentListener {
      private void textUpdated(DocumentEvent e) {
         try {
            inText = e.getDocument().getText(0, e.getDocument().getLength());
            word1.setText(String.format(FORMAT, inText));
         } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textUpdated(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textUpdated(e);

      }

      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textUpdated(e);
      }

   }

   private class FinishAction extends AbstractAction {
      public FinishAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
         if (comp == null) {
            return;
         }
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
         if (win == null) {
            return;
         }
         win.dispose();         
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TheSize2 theSize2 = new TheSize2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Size");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(theSize2);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: yes I did mean revalidate(), I just changed it. I fixed my program a little and recall the JTextField "size" on the constructor, but it is still not working. I imagine revalidate() reruns the constructor like repaint() reruns paint() or paintComponent()? By the way, I left a System.out.println("hi") in the "changedUpdate), why wouldn't it print one everytime I type something into the TextField since it should detact a chagne in my TextField. If not, I think KeyListener might actually work better than DocumentListener.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure if I made it clear, but I am trying to get my TextField to chagne the second the user start typing in the TextField or chagne it.

Comment: @user3618683: Yes, I know what you're trying to do, and again please let me be absolutely clear -- a KeyListener is **not** the way to do this. Again, use a DocumentListener as I have demonstrated above. You state, `"I think KeyListener might actually work better than DocumentListener"` -- not to be rude, but I've been at Swing a long time, and the minute you start fiddling with KeyListeners on text components, you risk messing up the functioning of the text components themselves. Seriously, just avoid using them in this and actually in most situations.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution with the help of Hovercraft Full Of Eels, all I missed was to re setSize. It is not the best solution, but it is simple enough for me to understand.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class TheSize extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    static String inText="";
    JPanel pane=new JPanel();
    JLabel word0=new JLabel("I would like my grid to be 2^",JLabel.RIGHT);
    JLabel word1=new JLabel("*  2^ "+inText,JLabel.RIGHT);
    JButton finish=new JButton("I'm done");
    JTextField size=new JTextField("",3);

    public TheSize(){
        super("size");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(550,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout box=new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(box);
        pane.add(word0);
        pane.add(size);
        pane.add(word1);
        pane.add(finish);
        finish.addActionListener(this);
        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        size.addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                    );
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ignore error
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TheSize();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        inText=size.getText();
        word1.setText("*  2^ "+inText);
        pane.revalidate();
        pane.repaint();

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }


}
```